# Best way to use a "python enum" with PySpark inside withColumn("myColumn", myEnum.Giraffe)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, enums

I'd like to do something like this:

```py
myEnum = Enum("myEnum", "Giraffe Crab Rat Human")

df_new = df.withColumn("AnimalEnumValueColumn", myEnum.Giraffe)
```

(I know this is incorrect, but I'd like an alternate solution that has the same intended effect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.value` to get the value from the enum object:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_new = df.withColumn("AnimalEnumValueColumn", F.lit(myEnum.Giraffe.value))
```

See the [enum docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) for more details.